# Main function calling twice in TYPO3

Tags: plugins, typo3, frontend

I have created a TYPO3 plugin using kickstarter.And I have `pi1` folder containing `class_pi1.php` class. And my problem is that whenever I am loading this class, its main function is executing twice. What might be the problem in this case?

Comment: please have a look at the extension configuration values in typoscript object browser.

Comment: I have checked ,but didnt find any error.

Comment: How is your plugin included on the page? Is it possible that there is more than one content element containing your plugin?

Comment: Plugin included only once from a content element ..

Comment: I've used a template where top most elements where reused in siblings. So adding the plugin in the top most page where enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

t3lib_extMgm::addPItoST43($_EXTKEY, 'pi1/class.tx_besijobs_pi1.php', '_pi1', 'list_type', 1);

have to change '1' to '0'.

t3lib_extMgm::addPItoST43($_EXTKEY, 'pi1/class.tx_besijobs_pi1.php', '_pi1', 'list_type', 0   );

Comment: You changed your plugin from an cached USER object ("1") to an uncached USER_INT ("0") object. This is not a good solution, even if it hides your problem.

Comment: Voted down.. because @maholtz has wrote the correct comment. This is a dirty solution for thIs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have embedded this element once.. if ext created by kickstarter, typoscript have to be ok. If plugin.tx_myext_pi1 is a type of USER, it always renders once, if embeded once.

"whenever I am loading this class" - What do you mean by "loading" a class? What do you do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by an other way.

I was using the method $this->cObj->convertToUserIntObject(); and looks like when it used, the plugin is executed a second time.

So, instead of let him do what he want, i stop him just after the method.

```
$this->cObj->convertToUserIntObject();

if ($this->cObj->doConvertToUserIntObject) {
     return;
}
```

The module is still executed a second time, but at least, I don't have any request done to the database.